# Eclipse: Shortcut to jump to matching tag of XML element

Tags: xml, eclipse, keyboard-shortcuts

I tried with CTRL + SHIFT + P, this works for brackets in code, but not in XML (tried different positions, before the opening tag, after, etc.).

There's CTRL + SHIFT + Arrow down/up to go to the next/previous element, this helps most cases, but I also need to jump to the matching tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd> is now working. Don't remember, maybe I reinstalled Eclipse or did an update. It's working now.

Comment: This shortcut is not working for me. Which eclise version do you use? And which XML Editor?

Comment: @Christopher Roscoe which os you are using?
if you are using Mac os then pres Command+shift+P

Answer (score 31):

@aleroot is correct. If you are using WTP XML editor. You can see this option in Navigate -> Go to -> Matching tag. Just a tip, for the complete list of shortcuts, you can use Control + Shift + L

[image: Matching tag]

Answer (score 15):

1. Position the cursor on the opening/closing tag you’re interested in. It can be anywhere in the tag.
2. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>></kbd>. Eclipse takes you to the matching opening/closing tag.

Comment: A point of distinction that helped me is that last character in the "Ctrl + Shift + >" key sequence is the greater than symbol and not one of the arrow keys. I have version 10 of Zend Studio but I'm using the old "Zend Studio" Scheme as set from the menu via "Window -> Preferences -> General -> Keys - Scheme" so this may not work for people using the Default Scheme (Eclipse I think) or one of the others (PDT & Emacs).